# Heap stable while rss increases node.js

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I have an app written in node.js and it works as it should. The only problem is that the memory keeps increasing 'till it hits 1.3Gb and immediately drops to ~400Mb. At first I though it's a memory leak, but further investigation shows there's no leaks.

[image: memory usage]

The analyze of heap-dump doesn't give any useful information, just proves that there's no leak. I'm using `node.js v4.2.1` and the application is heavily using `websockets (socket.io)` with transports set to `['websockets']` only. For load balancing I'm using `PM2 in cluster mode (4 instances)`.

What could be the reason? What are the consequences? Do you think it might crash the server in the long run?

Comment: Do you use socket-io adapter or sticky-cluster ?

Comment: @trquoccuong I use socket.io-redis

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to distribute the load of connections among different processes or machines with `pm2`, you have to make sure that requests associated with a particular session id connect to the process that originated them. If it connect wrong process , it will make a mass of request ajax to server . You can use inspector in browser to check it, refresh web an check socket run correctly. It will make memory increase faster and when it to limit , It will call gc().

Comment: I'm not using XHR Polling or JSONP Polling transports, only WebSocket, which doesn't need sticky sessions. gc() should be called periodically, so I still don't get why it's not cleaning memory until it reaches it's maximum, considering the fact that server is not busy at all (CPU ~20%), so there's nothing preventing gc() to do it's job.